# unexpected behavior of dict.keys on in

Tags: julia

for faster colision control I create dict which is used as sparse array from array of objects T2.
But this cod throw exeption

> KeyError: key [142, 69, 77] not found

Here us my code:

```
Ans=Dict{T1,Vector{T2}}()
for i in L
    pos=pos_func(i)
    if (pos in Ans.keys)
        push!(Ans[pos],i)
    else
        Ans[pos]=Vector{T2}([i])
    end
end
```

I catched event and printed pos, Ans.keys and (pos in Ans.keys). I found that pos is one of Ans.keys and (pos in Ans.keys)==True. But anyway I cannot get Ans[pos].

Julia Version 1.4.0 Commit b8e9a9ecc6 (2020-03-21 16:36 UTC)
What is the reason for such behaviour? Why same code can works half times?

Comment: When you post code examples, please make it so that they are entirely runnable. For example in this case: `T1`, `T2`, `L` and `pos_func` are missing.

Comment: I would advise against naming your variable `Ans`: it is customary to name variables with lower-case initial initial in Julia, and `ans` is special in the sense that it stores the last result in the REPL.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`keys()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.keys) function in order to get the keys of your dictionary instead of accessing the `keys` field. (Note that, in most cases, it is not a good idea to access internal fields of Julia objects, especially when accessor methods exist).

And in the particular case of testing whether a given key appears in a `Dict`, using [`haskey()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.haskey) would be even more idomatic.

The following should work:

```
# Some definitions so that your example is runnable
julia> T1 = Int;
julia> T2 = Int;
julia> L = 1:10;
julia> pos_func(i) = i%3;

julia> Ans=Dict{T1,Vector{T2}}()
Dict{Int64,Array{Int64,1}} with 0 entries

julia> for i in L
           pos=pos_func(i)
           if haskey(Ans, pos) # <- keys(Ans) instead of Ans.keys
               push!(Ans[pos],i)
           else
               Ans[pos] = T2[i] # or maybe simply [i], unless your collection L is heterogeneous
           end
       end

julia> Ans
Dict{Int64,Array{Int64,1}} with 3 entries:
  0 => [3, 6, 9]
  2 => [2, 5, 8]
  1 => [1, 4, 7, 10]
```

Comment: I think `haskey(Ans, pos)` is the preferred idiom here.

Comment: You're right, thanks! I edited my answer to mention this.